# What are the button codes for mouse scroll wheel left/right, in DECSET SGR 1006?

Tags: vim, xterm

> DECSET 1006
>
> The encoding takes the form of CSI < Cb ; Cx ; Cy M when a button is
>   pressed, and CSI < Cb ; Cx ; Cy m when a button is released, where:
>
> ```
> Each field is encoded as an ASCII integer.
> Cb is the button & keyboard modifiers.
> Cx is the column.
> Cy is the row.
> ```

(From https://github.com/chromium/hterm/blob/master/doc/ControlSequences.md - I've searched a lot, but this is the most detailed description I've. I might be searching it wrong)

What is the `Cb` button modifier for scroll wheel left and right?

It's 64/65 for scroll wheel up/down (i.e. buttons 1/2 + 64 [xterm, wheel mice](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Wheel-mice)), and these work in vim. Scroll wheel left/right might be 66/67, but this doesn't work in vim.

Actually, I don't really need the correct numbers - just the ones that `vim` accepts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll wheel *left/right* aren't detected by xterm, hence undocumented: there's no predefined **X event** which corresponds to this (though some creative use may have been made for a particular device).  If you're unsure about that, **`xev`** is useful for showing the events (though interpreting them can be hard).

Regarding [the link](https://github.com/chromium/hterm/blob/master/doc/ControlSequences.md), it doesn't appear to be complete, unless you're using [hterm](https://github.com/chromium/hterm).  In any case, [it's moved](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/hterm/doc/ControlSequences.md).

On the other hand, xterm detects scroll wheel *up/down* by button 4/5, using the **`translations`** resource (see the [default key-bindings](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings) in the manual).  The names **`Btn4Up`**, etc., are predefined in the X ToolKit to correspond with X events and (having been introduced in X11 in 1987) predate by roughly ten years their use for wheel mouse encoding.  While it's **possible** to extend those events, I haven't seen that it's been done (or used by vim, for that matter).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have a wheel mouse or  a PC or xev on my system. (I'm trying to modify a terminal emulator for android so left/right swipes are recognized as scrollwheelleft/right.). Insert mode in vim, plus ctrl-v will also show the escape codes. In the vim source the GUI hardwires mouse buttons to `<ScrollWheelLeft>` and `<ScrollWheelRight>`. So, I guess that's all there is?

Comment: Apparently that's all there is.

Comment: Thanks very much,  especially for adding the reference. BTW I audited the vim source code, and confirmed this independently. The GUI does handle it, but by directly mapping the mouse buttons.